# Generate bins with even number of samples in each

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, binning

I understand that I can generate bins for arrays with numpy using `numpy.histogram` or `numpy.digitize`, and have in the past. However, the analysis I need to do requires there to be an even number of samples in each bin, where the data is not uniformly distributed.

Say I have approximately normally distributed data in an array, `A = numpy.random.random(1000)`. How can I bin this data (either by creating an index or finding values which define the extents of each bin) in a way that there is an even number of samples in each?

I know this can be treated as an optimization problem, and can solve it as such, i.e.:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fmin

def generate_even_bins(A, n):
    x0 = np.linspace(A.min(), A.max(), n)

    def bin_counts(x, A):
        if any(np.diff(x)) <= 0:
            return 1e6
        else:
            binned = np.digitize(A, x)
            return np.abs(np.diff(np.bincount(binned))).sum()

    return fmin(bin_counts, x0, args=(A,))
```

... but is there something already available, perhaps in numpy or scipy.stats that implements this? If not shouldn't there be?

Comment: Hmh, isn't that just sorting and cutting at equal spaced indices?

Comment: Have you considered looking at [histogram equalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization)? It's a technique in image processing that takes a look at a histogram and increases contrast by ensuring that all intensities are equiprobable in occurrence... this is analogous to flattening the histogram so that each bin has the same count, which is what you're after.  Instead of looking at an image histogram, you can just look at a histogram of whatever you want - the technique still applies.  You're finding a probability transformation that allows each event to be equiprobable.

Comment: @cel good point... that would reduce my function down to 2-3 lines, simple enough and much more efficient.

Comment: @pbreach then also consider [`numpy.partition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html)